# sqldelight database setup for Compose Desktop, generated code is in wrong package

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, compose-desktop, sqldelight

So I'm trying to set up sqldelight for my Compose Desktop project I created using IntelliJ's wizard.
The generated project has its source code in `./src/JvmMain`. As it is a Desktop only project, there is no expected/actual setup with platform-specific source directories, it's just `jvmMain`.

Out of the box sqldelight set up following the guide [here](https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/2.0.0-rc01/jvm_sqlite/) doesn't find my `.sq` files. I assume because it either looks for `main` or `commonMain` (for multiplatform).

I can force it to look into `jvmMain` by configuring it like this:

```kotlin
sqldelight {
    databases {
        create("Database") {
            packageName.set("com.example.myproject.db")
            // manually setting the srcDir works
            srcDirs.setFrom("src/jvmMain/sqldelight")
        }
    }
}
```

This way it does generate my database code.
But the generated code ends up in `commonMain`, which is created by sqldelight, since it didn't exist in the project. How can I change the location of the generated code?